# Array of pointer to methods in swift

Tags: ios, selector, swift

I'm looking for a way to do something like an array of pointer to methods in C++ or an array of selector in objective-c.

With a class named `A` :

```
class A
{
    func function1() -> Int
    {
        // Do something cool here
        return 0;
    }

    func function2() -> Int
    {
        // Do something cool here
        return 1;
    }
}
```

I want to create an array of methods and call one of them using the index.

Here is an exemple of what I want to do with pseudo swift code :

```
let arr = [function1, function2 ]
arr[0]()
```

Comment: What problems are you having in your attempt to do so?

Comment: I've got an error with the `let arr = [function1, function2 ]` instruction (`use of unresolved identifier 'function1'`). This is 'pseudo-swift-code' because I have no idea of the syntax to do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is almost exactly correct. You just need to tie it to some instance (you can't call an instance method without an instance).

```
let a = A()

let arr = [a.function1, a.function2 ]
arr[0]()
```

Note that this is not the same thing as an array of selectors. Selectors are the *names* of methods, not the method themselves (they don't even have to refer to actual methods; they can just be names). You can send a selector to an arbitrary object in ObjC (if it doesn't respond, it'll throw an exception).